# mozilla firefox throwing error for jquery

Tags: jquery

I using jquery in my project

it is working properly in every browsers except mozilla

In mozilla the error,which is ($ is not defined) I am getting

Comment: have you included jquery library with async set to true?

Comment: please show us how you reference the script in your page.

Comment: @Vivek $(document).keydown(function(keyPressed)
        {//this code}          this is my code I am getting error in $ which is un defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like this,

```
$(window).delegate('*', 'keypress', function (e){
    alert("key pressed");
  });
```

OR

```
  jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function (e){
       alert('key pressed');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery syntax is tailor made for selecting HTML elements and perform some action on the element(s).

Basic syntax is: $(selector).action()

A dollar sign to define jQuery A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)

[more on this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp)

try this instead

```
jQuery('#Text').click(function () {
  jQuery('#Text').css('color', 'red');
});
```

enable javascript and disable "no-script" id you are using so